# How can I create a matrix as shown below in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix from a given vector in R, but I don't know how to achieve it in simple ways.  I am giving an example below. The matrix was made using the "cbind" function.

Given x as

```
[1,] 1
[2,] 3
[3,] 4
```

how can I create the matrix below with simple method?

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    3    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    4    3    1    0    0    0
[4,]    0    4    3    1    0    0
[5,]    0    0    4    3    1    0
[6,]    0    0    0    4    3    1
[7,]    0    0    0    0    4    3
[8,]    0    0    0    0    0    4
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this have a language associated with it or is this a math question?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous question, now it's clear. I am trying to do this in R.

Answer (score 4):

Using `append` and `sapply`

```
sapply(0:5, append, x = rep(0,5), values = c(1,3,4))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    3    1    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    4    3    1    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    4    3    1    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    4    3    1    0
# [6,]    0    0    0    4    3    1
# [7,]    0    0    0    0    4    3
# [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    4
```

Comment: Very nice solution, naming other arguments so that the iterator goes to the `after` argument in `append`.

Answer (score 3):

```
matrix(c(1,3,4,rep(0,6)),ncol=6,nrow=8)
```

You'll get a warning, but the correct matrix.  If you don't like the warning just use suppressWarnings:

```
suppressWarnings(matrix(c(1,3,4,rep(0,6)),ncol=6,nrow=8))
```

Of course, be careful with that function if you are trying to abstract this to more general cases.

Answer (score 2):

This works. (**edit**: no votes, maybe too telegraphic?)  The idea is to create an all-zero matrix with the appropriate dimensions, and then use row/column arithmetic (using the `row()` and `col()` functions) to fill in the desired values in the elements where `row-column` is between 0 and 2 (i.e. the diagonal and the first two lower off-diagonals).  This does rely on the column-major structure of matrices in R ...

```
x <- c(1,3,4)
n <- 6
m <- matrix(0,ncol=n,nrow=n+length(x)-1)
betw <- function(x,a,b) x>=a & x<= b
m[betw(row(m)-col(m),0,2)] <- x
```

Comment: And lots of recycling in the final assignment.  Yes, the better explanation of the idea really helps.

Answer (score 2):

This method is very intuitive:

```
x <- c(1,3,4)
n <- 6
m <- matrix(0,ncol=n,nrow=n+length(x)-1)
diag(m) <- 1
diag(m[-1,]) <- 3
diag(m[-c(1, 2),]) <- 4
```

Assigning along diagonals can be automated easily, for example with a 'for' loop

```
for(i in seq_along(x)) diag(m[1:n + i - 1,]) <- x[i]
```

Both approaches yield:

```
R> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    3    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    4    3    1    0    0    0
[4,]    0    4    3    1    0    0
[5,]    0    0    4    3    1    0
[6,]    0    0    0    4    3    1
[7,]    0    0    0    0    4    3
[8,]    0    0    0    0    0    4
```

Comment: It would look a lot better if the vector `x` were used in the solution (e.g., use a loop which performs the `diag<-` assignments).

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, added a for-loop implementation of the solution.

Comment: Thank you guys, all of these solutions work for me.  The method by mnel is really elegant!!